# IBDesignable errors when rendering storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ibdesignable

I tried to follow some guides as follows [1](https://medium.com/@ludovicjamet/how-to-use-storyboard-to-create-and-preview-custom-views-92acad7405fa) and [2](https://supereasyapps.com/blog/2014/12/15/create-an-ibdesignable-uiview-subclass-with-code-from-an-xib-file-in-xcode-6), but when I try to render a custom view in a storyboard I get an error.

> Failed to render and update auto layout status for View Controller. The agent threw an exception.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
@IBDesignable final class CustomView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        let customViewNib = loadFromNib()
        customViewNib.frame = bounds
        customViewNib.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth, UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleHeight]
        addSubview(customViewNib)
    }

    func loadFromNib() -> UIView {
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: Bundle.main)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
        return view
    }
}
```

And i have set the File Owner of my custom view.

I have create a new empty project faicing this issue:

https://github.com/ivangodfather/CustomView

or

https://ufile.io/imr9p

[image]

Comment: Please upload whatever is behind that ufile link onto this site. Either put the code or image here.

Comment: I cant upload my project here unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue it seems to be in the bundle.

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
let nib = UINib(nibName: String(describing: type(of: self)), bundle: bundle)
```

For more information to get the logs of the error you can see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42678873/2000162

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try this replace function

```
func loadFromNib() -> UIView {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
        return view
//        let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: Bundle.main)
//        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView
//        return view
    }
```