# Auto Layout Localization warnings showing in Issue Navigator but cannot see them in Autolayout pane in Storyboard (Xcode 9.3)

Tags: localization, autolayout, cocoapods, ibdesignable, xcode9.3

I had a project in Swift 3.2 that I converted to swift 4 in Xcode 9.3. After the successful migration, I got few Auto Layout Localization warnings that I fixed. My issue is that though I keep seeing such warnings in Issue Navigator and Auto Layout pane in Interface Builder shows yellow warning button, when I tap on it, I see no AutoLayout issues (See images below). 
[image: Warnings in Issue Navigator]

There are weird IBDesignables issues (above image) as well that some people on SO linked to cocoapod bug and workarounds but none have worked for me so far.
[image: Warning Button in AutoLayout Pane]
[image: No issues are shown here]

Moreover, my UI elements are not rendered at all. Only it marks their position and shows constraints. Please refer to the right pane. "Male Button" is not rendered at all. This doesn't happen for all view controllers in the storyboard but very annoying for few of them.
[image]

Comment: last issue of UI rendering got fixed by updating xcode

Answer (score 0):

Because your bundle refer to many view in swift 4 xcode 10.

So please manually choose your view that you're referring.

you can try: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56128426/4395342

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).