# All objects disappear in view controller (main storyboard) when I use custom @IBDesignable UITextfield class. (Xcode 10, Swift 4.2)

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode10, swift4.2

All objects disappear in view controller (main storyboard) when I use custom @IBDesignable UITextfield class. Main storyboard looks like this:

[image]

(Xcode 10, Swift 4.2)
As you see, it shows an error also. But Xcode shows 'Build Succeeded' when I run the app.

I use custom @IBDesignable UITextfield class like this below:

```
import UIKit
import AKMaskField

@IBDesignable

class MyTextFieldStyle: AKMaskField {

@IBInspectable var secureEntry : Bool = false

@IBInspectable var myBorderColor : UIColor = UIColor.white {
    didSet {
        self.layer.borderColor = myBorderColor.cgColor
    }
}

@objc func secureButtonPressed (sender: UIButton) {
    self.secureEntry = !self.secureEntry
    self.isSecureTextEntry = self.secureEntry
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib() 

    if self.secureEntry {

        let btn = UIButton(type: .custom)
        btn.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "eye-17-glyph-16"), for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.secureButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        btn.sizeToFit()

        btn.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.size.width-(btn.frame.size.width+5), y: (self.frame.size.height-btn.frame.size.height)/2, width: btn.frame.size.width, height: btn.frame.size.height)

        self.addSubview(btn)
    }

    self.layer.borderColor = self.myBorderColor.cgColor
}
}
```

It becomes fine when I close and open Xcode. It looks like a bug. This was working fine.

Comment: Are you running macOS Mojave 10.14 beta 11 on your machine?

Comment: Dear, @Alex7 Version 10.0 (10A255)

Comment: Yeah, I know that's the Xcode version you're using, but what about your macOS version?

Comment: sorry, macOS High Sierra, Version: 10.13.6 (17G65)

Comment: More than likely it seems like an Xcode 10.0 bug, especially since it was working fine not too long ago. Restarting Xcode seems tedious but may be your only resolve for now until they release a patch for this.

Comment: There is only one error Alex. It says "Failed to render and update auto layout status for RegsigerViewController (Rve-no-pOK): The agent crashed Main.storyboard" But it can work with this error. I mean Xcode shows 'Build Succeeded' when i run the app @Alex7

Comment: What version of cocoapods are you running? If its 1.5.0, downgrade to 1.4.0.

Comment: Dear, @Alex7, I googled an error explanation and then I follow these steps in the link below. Now It works. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732312/xcode-8-ib-designables-failed-to-render-and-update-auto-layout-status-the-a

Comment: By the way, pod version is 1.5.3 @Alex7

Comment: Did you have to upgrade or downgrade to fix your issue for @IBDesignable?

Comment: No upgrade no downgrade. I just follow steps in the link. (Actually this is my mistake because i did not focus error explanation. I just thought that this is an Xcode bug. Because i got this error after i update Xcode, it was working fine) Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732312/xcode-8-ib-designables-failed-to-render-and-update-auto-layout-status-the-a

Comment: Looks like Xcode 10.1 Beta has a fix for your issue regarding @IBDesignable. Read the release notes and tell me what you think. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_beta_release_notes

Comment: Dear @Alex7, yesterday it was a busy day. I just noticed that it happens again when I switch another view controller in main.storyboard and then I delete "DerivedData" like in the link and then all objects appear again. The link which i have shared yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732312/xcode-8-ib-designables-failed-to-render-and-update-auto-layout-status-the-a

Comment: As you wrote, Xcode 10.1 Beta has a fix this issue. Let me try it if i can download it.

Comment: Hey @Manny, did Xcode 10.1 Beta fix the issue?

Comment: @Alex7, Unfortunately Xcode beta shows also the same mistake: Failed to render and update auto layout status for SampleViewController (Rve-nopOK): The agent crashed Main.storyboard but Build Succeed