# Xcode 12.2 : error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): Failed to launch designables agent

Tags: swift, xcode

am getting below IB designable error below

error: IB Designables: Failed to render and update auto layout status for ViewController (BYZ-38-t0r): Failed to launch designable agent because the tool was shutting down. Check the console for a more detailed description and please file a bug report at feedbackassistant.apple.com.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LlqA.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BP9DT.png)

I tried solving this problem by using the answers on below link but it didn't work

[Xcode 8 - IB Designables - Failed to render and update auto layout status, The agent crashed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39732312/xcode-8-ib-designables-failed-to-render-and-update-auto-layout-status-the-a)

Comment: Do you happen to have any spaces in your project directory?

Comment: yes there was a space on the main folder that contains this project, I removed it but still, I have the same issue